# Upload image from React to Rails API with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, api, carrierwave

I'm trying to upload images from my react app to a rails api using the carrierwave gem. Up to this point I have tried many things and looked everywhere on the internet without finding a solution.

this is the request i'm sending
[request from react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqs3R.png)

but on the rails app, the event param is not being passed

> 07:57:37 api.1  | Started PATCH "/api/v1/events/8" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2018-05-24 07:57:37 -0600 07:57:37 api.1  | Processing by
>   Api::V1::EventsController#update as */* 07:57:37 api.1  |
>   Parameters: {"id"=>"8"} 07:57:37 api.1  |   Event Load (4.9ms)  SELECT
>   `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1 07:57:37
>   api.1  | Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
>   07:57:37 api.1  |  07:57:37 api.1  |  07:57:37 api.1  |    07:57:37
>   api.1  | ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the
>   value is empty: event): 07:57:37 api.1  |    07:57:37 api.1  |
>   app/controllers/api/v1/events_controller.rb:92:in `event_params'
>   07:57:37 api.1  | app/controllers/api/v1/events_controller.rb:56:in`
>   update'

If I sent using JSON.Stringify on the body of the request, it gets into the update function but carrierwave does nothing.

I know Carrierwave is working because if a upload an image using ActiveAdmin it works fine.

Here is the action where i create the request

```
export const uploadMainImage = (event, eventId) => {

    return (dispatch) => {
        //dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST });
        //console.log(window.location);
        let upload = {
            event
        }
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: uploadAuthHeader(),
            body: upload
        };
        console.log("request:");
        console.log(requestOptions);
        //window.fetch(window.location.origin + '/api/v1/events/image_upload/' + eventId, requestOptions)
        window.fetch(window.location.origin + '/api/v1/events/' + eventId, requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
              dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS, payload: response });
          })
          .catch(error => {
                //console.log(error);
                dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE, payload: error })
          })
    };
}
```

This are the headers:

```
export function uploadAuthHeader() {
    // return authorization header with jwt token
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

    if (user && user.auth_token) {
        return { 

            //'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + user.auth_token 
        };
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Here is where I handle the files selection from react-dropzone

```
readFile(files) {


        const event = {
            imagen: files[0]
        }

        this.props.uploadMainImage(event, this.props.match.params.eventId);

    }
```

On the rail side, this is my Model

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :imagen, ImagenUploader
end
```

and Uploader from Carrierwave was not modified from the default.

UPDATE------
This is my event_controller.rb, I'm using the default udate method of the controller

```
module Api
  module V1
    class EventsController < ApiController
      before_action :authenticate_request, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
      before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :image_upload]


      # GET /events
      # Entrego los eventos especificos del usuario loggeado.
      def index
        @events = @current_user.events
        if params[:page]
          @events = @events.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
          pageCount = @events.total_pages
        else
          #@events = Event.order('fecha ASC')
          pageCount = 1
        end
        render json: { events: @events, meta: { pages: pageCount, records: @events.count } }
      end

      # GET /events/1
      def show
        render json: @event
      end

      # GET /events/upcoming
      def upcoming
        @events = Event.where('fecha >= ?', Date.today).order(:fecha)
        if params[:page]
          @events = @events.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
          pageCount = @events.total_pages
        else
          #@events = Event.order('fecha ASC')
          pageCount = 1
        end

        render json: { events: @events, meta: { pages: pageCount, records: Event.count } }
      end

      # POST /events
      def create
        @event = Event.new(event_params)
        #@event.imagen = event_params[:imagen][:preview]

        if @event.save
          #@event.imagen = event_params[:imagen][:preview]
          render json: @event, status: :created#, location: @event
        else
          render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /events/1
      def update
        if @event.update(event_params)
          render json: @event
        else
          render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end


      # DELETE /events/1
      def destroy
        @event.destroy
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_event
          @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
        def event_params
          params.require(:event).permit!
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Also from Active Admin, the event.rb file, I just permitted the :imagen field, and when i upload from active admin it works fine without any changes in the controller.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Event do
# See permitted parameters documentation:
# https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters
#
# permit_params :list, :of, :attributes, :on, :model
#
# or
#
# permit_params do
#   permitted = [:permitted, :attributes]
#   permitted << :other if params[:action] == 'create' && current_user.admin?
#   permitted
# end
permit_params :nombre, :user_id, :hora, :fecha, :lugar, :meta, :inicio_inscripcion, 
    :fin_inscripcion, :costo_inscripcion, :pagina_web, :logo, :numero_inicial, 
    :nombre_contacto, :telefono_contacto, :email_contacto, :imagen, :string

end
```

Please i need a hand to figure out how to upload the images from my React app to the Rails API.

Second UPDATE

This is the POST request from active_admin

Started POST "/admin/events/6" for ::1 at 2018-05-24 11:54:48 -0600
11:54:48 api.1  | Processing by Admin::EventsController#update as HTML
11:54:48 api.1  |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9BqST8qDLEJbDlfd6Xs/+YCDMy9qPeCcbOOxbjIGbDoTBRaGAVRU48rqI+E3kD9ORbsiBguS/emJN9JIM+StuQ==", "event"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "nombre"=>"Carrera con Foto", "hora_inicio(1i)"=>"2018", "hora_inicio(2i)"=>"5", "hora_inicio(3i)"=>"24", "hora_inicio(4i)"=>"", "hora_inicio(5i)"=>"", "fecha_inicio(1i)"=>"", "fecha_inicio(2i)"=>"", "fecha_inicio(3i)"=>"", "hora(1i)"=>"2018", "hora(2i)"=>"5", "hora(3i)"=>"24", "hora(4i)"=>"", "hora(5i)"=>"", "fecha(1i)"=>"2018", "fecha(2i)"=>"5", "fecha(3i)"=>"27", "lugar"=>"Villa Olimpica", "meta"=>"", "inicio_inscripcion(1i)"=>"2018", "inicio_inscripcion(2i)"=>"5", "inicio_inscripcion(3i)"=>"17", "fin_inscripcion(1i)"=>"2018", "fin_inscripcion(2i)"=>"5", "fin_inscripcion(3i)"=>"25", "costo_inscripcion"=>"123", "pagina_web"=>"", "logo"=>"", "numero_inicial"=>"100", "nombre_contacto"=>"Hector Toro", "telefono_contacto"=>"50498761065", "email_contacto"=>"htorohn@gmail.com", "imagen"=>#, @original_filename="IMG_0008.PNG", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[imagen]\"; filename=\"IMG_0008.PNG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Update Event", "id"=>"6"}

UPDATE 3.

I made the changes proposed from Bill, however the event param still not getting to the rails app.

07:59:02 api.1  | Started PATCH "/api/v1/events/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-25 07:59:02 -0600
07:59:02 api.1  | Processing by Api::V1::EventsController#update as */*
07:59:02 api.1  |   Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
07:59:02 api.1  |   Event Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
07:59:02 api.1  | Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
07:59:02 api.1  | 
07:59:02 api.1  | 
07:59:02 api.1  |
07:59:02 api.1  | ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: event):
07:59:02 api.1  |
07:59:02 api.1  | app/controllers/api/v1/events_controller.rb:95:in `event_params'
07:59:02 api.1  | app/controllers/api/v1/events_controller.rb:56:in`update'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meQOR.png)

Comment: Can you post the code for your API controller?  In your react code, you're passing the event in the request body, but it seems your controller expects it as a request param.  Showing us your events.rb active admin file might be useful for comparison too.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your comment, I added the files you mentioned to the post.

Comment: so, I'm getting a better picture.  Can you post an #update request log when updating the Event through active admin?  I already have a theory.  I'm going to answer now, but please post that request log when you can.  I think we can surely figure it out from that.

Comment: I updated the post with the request from active_admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looking at your active admin permitted parameters vs. your own EventsController permitted parameters, there seems to be a discrepancy as to what's permitted and expected versus what you're sending from your Javascript.  I'm extrapolating your `events` table schema from your code.  I can't reproduce your code locally, because I don't have it all.  But this is what I think will work:

You need to pass the image file data in the body, as you were trying, but it needs to be encoded in the body with a parameter name (`event[imagen]`). Try this:

```
export const uploadMainImage = (imageFile, eventId) => {

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("event[imagen]", imageFile);

    return (dispatch) => {
        //dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_REQUEST });
        //console.log(window.location);
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'PATCH',
            headers: uploadAuthHeader(),
            body: data
        };
        console.log("request:");
        console.log(requestOptions);
        window.fetch(window.location.origin + '/api/v1/events/' + eventId, requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
              dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS, payload: response });
          })
          .catch(error => {
                //console.log(error);
                dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_IMAGE_FAILURE, payload: error })
          })
    };
}


readFile(files) {
    var imageFile = files[0];  // assumes files[0] is from your file form input
    this.props.uploadMainImage(imageFile, this.props.match.params.eventId);
}
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer, I tried it but still the event param is not being passed, I updated the post with the console from rails and an image with the request from react.

Comment: @HectorToro, sorry, I was thinking of jQuery $.ajax.  I have updated my answer.  Let me know if it helps.

Comment: man, thank you very much, the latest solution worked really good, just had to comment this line in the header — ‘Content-Type’: ‘multipart/form-data’ — if a Content-Type is present, the request is not parsed correctly.